# Too much blank space in the spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a beginner devoloper. I'have a problem with Spinner in my xml file.
The spinner is this:

[image]

```
 <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerA"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Symbol A"
                android:entries="@array/teamList"/>
```

There is too much black space between the end of text and the down arrow of spinner. As you can see, the word "Atalanta" is truncated in Atala.., but there is a lot of blank space on the right. How can I solve?
 Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, adding android.paddingRight=0dp to the Spinner. In this way, there is more free space and the word "Atalanta" is not truncated in Atala..

Answer (score 0):

Replace -

```
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with -

```
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and when you see the output in any device , you will see the proper output.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, but this solution doesn't work. I tried also to remove gravity attribute, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `listPreferredItemPaddingEnd` in the default layout `simple_list_item_1`.

So you can use your own spinner adapter with your own layout item.

You need to create an `arrayAdapter`, override the `getView` method and return your own item view.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that solution, but since I'm a beginner I hoped in something simpler :-)